# Dialog in button not clickable

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface

By default, when a dialog is created the option for clicking the buttons in the footer is disabled.

Is there something that I missed when creating them?

```
<ui:Dialog x:Name="modal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" >

<ui:Button Content="TEST" Margin="0,10,0,0"/>

</ui:Dialog>
```

This event will never be hit:

```
modal.ButtonLeftClick += (_, _) =>
{
};
```

[image]

Link where the current documentation is present: https://wpfui.lepo.co/documentation/Wpf.Ui.Controls.Dialog.html

Comment: The code tries to add an event handler for the left button click event of a dialog box, but there is no left button or footer section in the code, so the event handler won't work. Dialog boxes disable buttons in the footer section by default, so you need to use the "Footer" property to add a button or a group of buttons and attach event handlers to enable them and add functionality. Check the official documentation of the UI framework or library for dialog boxes.

Comment: The buttons are in the footer of the dialog, the problem is that they can not be clicked. I added a snip with the ui.

Comment: can you try this
modal.ButtonLeftClick += (sender,e) =>
{
    // do something
};

Comment: I tried, as I sed in  the description of the questions. The code attached to the event will not be hit, because the buttons cannot be clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Change the index of the user control.

```
<ui:Dialog x:Name="modal" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" **Panel.ZIndex="10"** >

</ui:Dialog>
```